# Chess figurines for kindle, both eink and kindle fire

Tags: graphics, chess, kindle

I wrote 13 chess books, using images, well seen on every kind of kindle, old and new. However, they mantain the same size when you change the size of the text.

I just saw an old post by Asim, who reverted to the use of images for figurines, like I am doing.

However today I saw on Amazon a book by a known author where figurines scale well.

Is there now a method using LaTeX where the pieces are seen as figurines on any kind of kindle? both old and new.

Thanks if someone can help.

ADDITIONAL DETAILS POSTED ON AUGUST 6th

A full example of the way I use figurines instead of chess pieces can be found here, by looking inside:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00AUWJEKA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AUWJEKA)

I was the second author to use the trick of using png images, the result being long time best seller. The problem was to prepare the images so they could be seen properly in all the dimensions available for the text, as the letter did change size, but not the images.

After three years everybody is doing that now.

Somebody tried to use embedded fonts, but that did not work on B/W eink displays, the traditional Kindle.

Recently a famous author published a wonderful looking book when seen on the Kindle Fire: Andrew Soltis, The inner game of chess.

yesterday I came on this site where I saw that Asim (Pereira) abandoned and went back to using images.

Mind that in the States Kindle Fire is used, while in Europe eink displays are used.

Therefore the question is:

does anybody know a system (not using images) where the resulting figurines are scalable like the fonts and well seen on all the Kindle devices on the market now? when preparing the mobi and azw files with calibre, it's possible  to chose the option "both old and new" but embedded fonts do not work on the eink kindles.

It's a problem similar to tables, I used a system equivalent that worked well on eink displays that do not support tables, now with Kindle Voyage that's not working anymore. Amazon makes difficult to prepare something that works for all models.

Comment: HI, i first thought this would be spam, but apparently there is a real question buried in here. Can you show us with a minimal working example how you generate the figurines?

Comment: we really need some more details on your setup.

Comment: A full example of the way i use figurines instead of capital letters can be seen her

Comment: The boards look like the regular ones with regular chess fonts produced by LaTeX packages to me. I'm not sure what you mean by 'figurines'. In any case, we need a minimal working example i.e. code.

Comment: I am not talking about the boards, they are png images.  But about the text, where instead of seeing a move Qh4 you see an icon of Q and the letters h4. This is called a figurine. I use a small png image that has a fixed size. increaing the font size, letters become smaller or bigger, while the icon size remains unchanged. Giving problems in clearly seeing the move. Alternative systems use embedded fonts, where the Q is actually an ASCII code representing the icon. This works on Kindle Fire, but not on eink displays, not supporting embedded fonts. I wonder if tex could fix this in a mobi file.

Comment: I checked on my (rather old) e-ink kindle. It shows good figurines which scales, they looked like this one http://decodeunicode.org/u+2654/zoom. But I doubt that is is done with fonts, they are probably images which are scaled relative to the font size. On the kindle reader of my smartphone (rather old too) other figurines are used - they look more geometric but I didn't recognize the source.

Comment: If they scale they are not images but fonts (I use images, and they have a fixed size in pixels). Can you please give me the title of the book and the model of your eink kindle?  Besides, do you have any idea about how this is done, or can someone suggest a method? (That works on eink kindles, as on Kindle Fire there is no problem)

Comment: You should notify me with @...if you answer to comment. Images can scale with the font: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259123/how-can-i-display-an-image-using-the-em-unit. I don't know if you do it in a kindle but it is imho more probable that something like this is used in the Soltis book than some font. You should better discuss this in some ebook forum, it is not a tex question.